# AIX (no GNU sed/awk) join line if it does NOT have control M or \r character at the end

Tags: awk, sed, aix

I am looking for way to join line if the file does not control M character. AIX has its standard awk and sed utility but not GNU

The issue: we get file from 3rd party , from windows. And the file has ^M (i.e. \r) character at end of each line, expect for some lines , in which the data in some field itself has \n character. Hence there is need to join the lines which has this extra \n character.

Data example :

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|^M
a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|^M
b1|b2|b3|b
4|b5|^M
c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|^M
```

expected output.

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|^M
a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|^M
b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|^M
c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|^M
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there a `\n` between the `b` and the `4`? If you are unsure, run `cat -vet yourFile`

Comment: yes it has it, i see "$" sign after "b" i.e. for the line having this issue.

Comment: `unix2dos` will handle that.

Comment: Obviously the lines with control m have \r and \n , right?

Comment: `cat -vet` does not provide good info to me. Pipe a line with control M to `|od -t x1c` to strip it down lines to ascii hex. `\r` would appear as `0d`, and `\n` will appear as `0a`.

Comment: following answer from @kdhp work . Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, perl is handling really good transformations of \n, \r , etc, without the restrictions of non gnu sed - actually `perl -pe` can replace sed directly.

So this operation worked fine in BSD :

```
$ echo -ne "abc\r\ndef\nijk\r\nlmn\r\n" |cat -vte
abc^M$
def$
ijk^M$
lmn^M$

$ echo -ne "abc\r\ndef\nijk\r\nlmn\r\n" |perl -pe "s/\r\n/\0/g;s/\n//g;s/\0/\r\n/g" |cat -vte
abc^M$
defijk^M$
lmn^M$
```

Answer (score 0):

A literal carriage-return can be used by typing `^V` (Ctrl-V) followed by the "Return" key.

The following `sed(1)` script loops over lines that do not end in a carriage-return, removing the undesired line-feeds:

```
sed '
:label
/^M$/! {
    N
    s/\n//
    blabel
}'
```

As one line:

```
sed -e ':l' -e '/^M$/!{N;s/\n//;bl' -e '}'
```

Comment: Have you test this in BSD/non GNU Sed?? I think it is not working. BSD sed does not directly allow `\n` in replace operation `s/`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Yes I have, and the `\n` is in the [regular-expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02), not the substitution.

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot KDHP, the solution worked for me .

Comment: Also can I somehow use \r instead of ^M , some other way. I want to use the one line solution as part of shell script , which connects to this server over ssh and connects. I do not have much permissions on the server, even to create file.

Comment: I think following seems to be working, @kdhp or any sed expert , please review:  sed -e ':l' -e '/'$(echo "\015")'$/!{N;s/\n//;bl' -e '}' sample.txt

Comment: @MeRicl Any use of `echo(1)` containing a reverse-solidus (```\```) is implementation defined behaviour, and there should be no issue with the use of a literal carriage-return (`^M`) in a shell script.